# Слайдер на JS, проблема с переходом по точкам

Tags: javascript, slider

Добрый вечер.
Делаю свою первую самый простой слайдер, так вот, я хотел добавить переход по точкам(внизу слайдера) и у меня это получилось, но в слишком колхозный способ.Есть ли более разумный способ это сделать?

```js
window.onload = function(){
var images=['http://www.poessiger.com/downloads/faser_800x600.jpg','http://www.visit-montenegro.com/downloads/wallpaper-800x600-2.jpg','http://www.poessiger.com/downloads/flasche_800x600.jpg','http://magazine.uchicago.edu/views/view1_800x600.jpg','http://www.wollemipine.com/images/wp_wallpaper8_800x600.jpg'], counter=0;
var prev = document.getElementById('prev');
var next = document.getElementById('next');
var dot=document.getElementsByClassName('dotted');
dot[0].style.background="white";
prev.onclick = function(){
 dot[counter].style.background ='#e0e0e0';
 var slider=document.getElementById('pic');
 counter--;
 if(counter<0){
  counter=images.length-1;
 }
 slider.src=images[counter];
 dot[counter].style.background ='white';
};
next.onclick = function(){
 dot[counter].style.background ='#e0e0e0';
 var slider=document.getElementById('pic');
 counter++;
 if(counter==images.length){
  counter=0;
 }
 slider.src=images[counter];
 dot[counter].style.background ='white';
};

dot[0].onclick = function(){
 var slider=document.getElementById('pic');
 dot[counter].style.background ='#e0e0e0';
 counter=0;
 slider.src=images[counter];
 dot[counter].style.background ='white';
};
dot[1].onclick = function(){
 var slider=document.getElementById('pic');
 dot[counter].style.background ='#e0e0e0';
 counter=1;
 slider.src=images[counter];
 dot[counter].style.background ='white';
};
dot[2].onclick = function(){
 var slider=document.getElementById('pic');
 dot[counter].style.background ='#e0e0e0';
 counter=2;
 slider.src=images[counter];
 dot[counter].style.background ='white';
};
dot[3].onclick = function(){
 var slider=document.getElementById('pic');
 dot[counter].style.background ='#e0e0e0';
 counter=3;
 slider.src=images[counter];
 dot[counter].style.background ='white';
};
dot[4].onclick = function(){
 var slider=document.getElementById('pic');
 dot[counter].style.background ='#e0e0e0';
 counter=4;
 slider.src=images[counter];
 dot[counter].style.background ='white';
};


};
```

```css
img{
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 object-fit: cover;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
button{
 height: 300px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 background: lightgreen;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.dot{
 /*background: black;*/
 height: 15px;
}
.dotted{
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 background: #e0e0e0;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Slider</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="slider" class="slider"> 
 <button id="prev">Prev</button>
  <img src="http://www.poessiger.com/downloads/faser_800x600.jpg" alt="" id="pic">
  <button id="next">Next</button>
 </div>
 <div class="dot">
  <div id="dotted" class="dotted"></div>
  <div id="dotted" class="dotted"></div>
  <div id="dotted" class="dotted"></div>
  <div id="dotted" class="dotted"></div>
  <div id="dotted" class="dotted"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Делегирование.
2. Сохраняйте свойства каждой точки в ней же (или `uid` для поиска в хранилище, если данных много).

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper'),
    handler = e => {
      console.info(`Я точка картинки #${e.dataset.id}!`);
    };

wrapper.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let dot = e.target.closest('.dot'); // Ищем ближайшего предка-точку, включая проверку себя
  
  if(!dot && !wrapper.contains(dot)) // Если таких нет или есть, но вне раппера
    return;                          // Выходим
  
  handler(dot);
});
```

```css
.dot{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
 <div class="dot" data-id="1"></div>
 <div class="dot" data-id="2"></div>
 <div class="dot" data-id="3"></div>
 <div class="dot" data-id="4"></div>
 <div class="dot" data-id="5"></div>
</div>
```